# android run my application give error i missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I run my application on my android phone and it gives me the message Missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in `AndroidManifest.xml`

The manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sparrow.math1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Math Quiz"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sparrow.math1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.sparrow.math1.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.sparrow.math1.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.sparrow.math1.resultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity 
           android:name="com.sparrow.math1.CatagoryTest"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>



<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />       
           </application>


</manifest>
```

Error Giving this page

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class CatagoryTest extends Activity {
    Intent intent;
    DataBaseHelper dbh;
    Cursor c;
    ListView lst;
    View v;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    BaseAdapter basea;
    private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-5660543815588540/4886657317";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catagory);     
        v=(View) findViewById(R.id.testcat);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.math);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testcat);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        try {
            dbh=new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            if(dbh.createDataBase()==true){ }   
            dbh.openDataBase();     

            c=dbh.catagorydata();
            c.moveToFirst();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

        try{
        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.catList);

        listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems); 


        lst.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150,206,206,246));  
        //lst.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CECEF6"));
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
        listItems.clear();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error  : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        try{
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            listItems.add(""+c.getString(0));
            c.moveToNext();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }   
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        lst.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,int position, long id) {               
                  int no=lst.getCheckedItemPosition();
                  String cat=(String) lst.getItemAtPosition(no);
                  Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.sparrow.math1.Main.class);
                  intent.putExtra("category", cat);
                  startActivity(intent);                
              }
        });     


    }
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
}
```

Please give me suggestion for remove this error.
I am new in android. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

You need to declare that you are using ads in the manifest, it should work after that